# How can I change the index of a NEST (ElasticSearch) scroll request?

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

We have two indexes for each document type, a draft and a published index.  Normally setting the index we want to work with is easy but I can't see how to do it with the scroll API.

The initial request is ok.

```
var query = new SearchDescriptor<MyDoc>()
            .Index(MyDoc.DraftIndexName) <-- we can switch them here
            // Or .Index(MyDoc.PublishedIndexName)
            .Size(pageSize)
            .Query(q =>
                 ...
            ))
            .Scroll("2m");
```

but when I want to get the next page

```
var request = new ScrollDescriptor<MyDoc>()
                .ScrollId(scrollId)
                .Scroll(new Time("2m"));
                // Nowhere to set the index


var scrollResponse = await client.ScrollAsync<EsPerson>(request);
```

I assume it will always use the default index via inference which is the draft one.

Answer (score 0):

The start of scrolling is initiated with a request to the search API, which returns a scroll ID in the response. After that, the scroll ID from a response is passed to the scroll API to continue scrolling through all documents, repeating until no more documents are returned. All subsequent scroll API calls will use the configuration of the initial API call, including the index/indices targeted.

If scrolling is considered to be like a server-side cursor, where the initial request defines the parameters for scrolling, it doesn't make much sense to be able to change these parameters *mid-scroll*.

Comment: I don't want to change them mid scroll. However you have help me find the answer.  On first look at the requests I saw the calls had to be /{index}/_search?scroll=1m, However only the first call has the index name in the url.  The follow on scroll requests are just /_search/scroll. So there is no need to set the index.  Thanks for making me look again.

Comment: Not suggesting that you want to change them mid-scroll, just that if the ability to set them on a scroll request were there, it would imply that you could, but you can't :) You may want to take a look at `ScrollAll<T>()` to help with scrolling many documents.